# Como puedo habilitar o desabilitar a un cliente

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7

**esta es mi tabla de cliente , no se si este bien ponerlo asi o con un boton habilitar o desabilitar**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('Nombre');
            $table->string('Telefono');
            $table->string('Celular');
            $table->string('Email')->unique();
            $table->text('Direccion');
            $table->boolean('Habilitado')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**esta es mi tabla donde muestro los datos No se si ahi se debe de poner un boton para activar o desactivar al cliente, Lo que quiero hacer es que si en un momento a ese cliente no se le quiere vender se desactive y no puedan hacer ninguna operacion con él**

```
<table id="tablaCliente" class="table table-light table-bordered table-hover table-responsive-md" style="width:100%">
<thead class="thead-light">
    <tr >
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Teléfono</th>
        <th>Celular</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Dirección</th>   
        <th>Habilitado</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($clientes as $cliente)
    <tr>
    <td>{{ $cliente->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $cliente->Nombre }}</td>
        <td>{{$cliente->Telefono}}</td>
        <td>{{$cliente->Celular}}</td>
        <td>{{$cliente->Email}}</td>
        <td>{{$cliente->Direccion}}</td>
        <td>{{$cliente->Habilitado}}</td>
        <td>


<!-- Button trigger modal --><button type="button" onclick="getFormulario('{{ url('clientes/'.$cliente->id.'/edit') }}')" style="display: inline" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Editar
  </button>
            <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/clientes/'.$cliente->id) }}" style="display: inline">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro de eliminar este cliente?');">Borrar</button>
            
            </form>
            
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```

Comment: podrias colocar el resto de tu codigo que as intentado hasta ahora??

Comment: Que has intentado? Pues al momento solo vemos una migración pero no alguna implementación

Comment: ya Añadi más codigo a mi pregunta , no se si sea necesario , si necesitan ver mas codigo me lo hacen saber.

Comment: Ocupamos la consulta que tienes al momento para mostrar los clientes en tu vista

Comment: Creo que si lo que quieres es cambiar la tabla Habilitado entre true y false, talvez necesitas crear una funcion post, para que hagas eso, no es necesario utilizar el metodo delete, eso opino, dentro del controlador, pues le mandas false, o true lo que necesitas.